# ¿Como agrego texto a un widget Text en Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Por motivos de simplicidad, mi "formulario" se ve algo asi:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

mensaje = tk.Text(ventana, background="white", width=165, height=25)
mensaje.config(state="disable")
mensaje.pack(padx=0, pady=125)

mensaje.insert(INSERT, "Hola Mundo")

ventana.mainloop()
```

Entiendo que `mensaje.insert(INSERT, "Hola Mundo")` deberia agregar el texto requerido a mi widget, pero obtengo este error:

> File "busqueda.py", line 5, in 
>       mensaje.insert(INSERT, "Hola Mundo") NameError: name 'INSERT' is not defined

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Kenny te falta indicar el namespace, `tk.INSERT`, tambien puedes especificarlo como una cadena `mensaje.insert("insert", "Hola Mundo")` . Si no recuerdo mal no te insertara el texto si esta en estado `disabled`.

Comment: @FJSevilla En efecto, eso lo soluciono. No se si es mi imaginacion, pero la documentacion es algo confusa por todas partes. Si desea poner una respuesta la dare por aceptada, sino muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Kenny he dejado una respuesta que como siempre me ha quedado demasiado larga.... Y no, no es tu imaginación, la documentación de tkinter no esta del todo a la altura del resto en Python (Hay que tener en cuenta que aunque viene incluido en Python para Windows es un framework de desarrollo independiente y disponible para otros lenguajes). Generalmente la gente recurre a la de effbot.org, personalmente no me gusta nada. Una que esta bastante bien es http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html, solo le faltan ejemplos. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT` es una variable definida dentro del módulo `tkinter` y que tiene como valor la cadena `'insert'`. En realidad, según las convenciones de Python es una constante (identificador en mayúsculas deben ser tratados como constantes, teniendo en cuenta que el concepto de constante no existe en Python como tal.)

Al  pertenecer al modulo `tkinter` y realizar el import de la forma `import tkinter as tk` hay que indicar el espacio de nombres al que pertenece:

```
mensaje.insert(tk.INSERT, "Hola Mundo")
```

---

La confusión viene porque en gran parte de la documentación de tkinter se saltan a la torera lo que dicen los PEPs y el propio zen de Python sobre los imports. Es muy común que se importe de la forma `from tkinter import *`, esto es en general una mala práctica, la única justificación posible es que se quieran sobrescribir los widgets de tkinter con los de ttk, y aun así no me gusta :).

`from tkinter import *` importa todas las globals al namespace actual, por lo que `mensaje.insert(INSERT, "Hola Mundo")` es válido. El problema es que esto puede provocar colisiones con otros imports o con nuestras propias variables, pobla el espacio de nombres actual sin necesidad y terminamos por no saber claramente de donde viene cada cosa.

El zen de Python dice:

> - Explícito mejor que implícito.
> - Los espacios de nombres son una buena idea, hagamos más de esto.
> - La legibilidad cuenta.

No tiene sentido tirarlo todo por la borda por ahorrarnos `tk.` (o `std::` en C++ y su `using namespace std`...). Con `tk.INSERT` sabemos a quien pertenece esa variable y no entra nunca en conflicto con otra variables llamadas `INSERT` en nuestro propio módulo o en otros imports.

Al igual que el [resto de constantes](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter-module.html#section-Variables) como `N`, `NW`, `CENTER`, etc pueden ser sustituidos en los métodos donde se usan sustituyéndolas por su valor

```
mensaje.insert("insert", "Hola Mundo")
```

---

El método [`tkinter.Text.insert`](http://%60) recibe como primer argumento el índice donde se va a insertar el texto, el segundo es el texto en sí y el tercero es una tupla con las etiquetas asociadas a ese texto y que es opcional. El índice se puede especificar de muchas formas ([ver documentación](http://mensaje.insert(tk.INSERT,%20%22Hola%20Mundo%22))). Con `tk.INSERT` indicamos que el índice donde se debe insertar es la posición actual del cursor en el widget `Text`.

Por último, indicar que no se puede insertar texto ni mediante código ni mediante la entrada estándar si el `Text` tiene el estado como `"disabled"`.